# gradle: how to run task only if file timestamp older than newest source code timestamp

Tags: gradle

In gradle build I have task that builds, bundle and copy JS files from another directory inside my application structure. 
How I can set a condition - run this task only if bundle timestamp is older than latest JS source code timestamp.

Comment: I think you can use incremental task feature to achive that: see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#incremental_tasks

Comment: Looks like I need to dive deep into "Up-to-date checks (AKA Incremental Build)". Thank you for pointing to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to declare the `.js` files as an input to the task which does the bundling and the bundle as an output. Then Gradle's incremental build will do the rest.

Like you already noted, the whole documentation is in the [incremental build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) section in the userguide.

Essentially, your task needs to look like this:

```
class BundleTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFiles
    ConfigurableFileCollection jsSource = project.files()

    @OutputFile
    File bundleFile

    @TaskAction
    void bundle() {
        // do the actual bundling, using jsSource and writing to bundleFile
    }
}
```